# change Gazebo initial position of the arm

Tags: gazebo, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how to change the arm(Jaco2) starting position in Gazebo. Currently the only thing that I do is to execute the move_robot.py script (modified with my desired position), but this represent a problem in my case since the arm is integrated on the top of the Husky robot and the initial pre-imposted movement cause an overturning of this latter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258246/change-gazebo-initial-position-of-the-arm/) by [pietroastolfi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27092/pietroastolfi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set the initial joint positions like in this example: [hector_tracker_gazebo_launch/launch/spawn_default.launch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_tracker_gazebo/blob/master/hector_tracker_gazebo_launch/launch/spawn_default.launch#L28)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2